# Declaring points in array for drawing polygon in VB 2019

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to declare a constant array where i can declare the points for drawing a polygon?

Something along the lines like:

```
Dim myPoints As Point() = {{10,10}, {12,12}, {13,13}, {14,14}, {15,15}} 
...
...
...
myGraphics.DrawPolygon(myPen, myPoints)
```

The idea is hardcoding the points using the least posible code

Comment: What you have on the right there is an array of arrays, not an array of `Points`. If you want a `Point` then you have to actually create a `Point`. How would you create a `Point` to assign to a variable? That's exactly how you create a `Point` to assign to an array element.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize an array of [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.8) like this

```vb
Dim myPoints = {
    New Point(10, 10),
    New Point(12, 12),
    New Point(13, 13),
    New Point(14, 14),
    New Point(15, 15)
}
```

or put it all on one line, which looks just like your multidimensional array version.

```vb
Dim myPoints = {New Point(10, 10), New Point(12, 12), New Point(13, 13), New Point(14, 14), New Point(15, 15)}
```

We can also instead use a jagged array which LINQ can operate on to select new Points

```vb
Dim myPoints =
    {New Integer() {10, 11}, New Integer() {12, 13}, New Integer() {14, 15}}.
    Select(Function(p) New Point(p(0), p(1))).ToArray()
```

Comment: this is more of what i was looking for... i wonder if it can be reduced more... thanks for the answer

Comment: @Vega_Ska the G3nt_M3caj ansower shortens the code required, potentially turning `New Point(10, 10)` into `NewPoint(10, 10)` (you save one space `" "` per) but you need to declare that func. You could also call it `Dim a As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Point)` and turn it into `a(10, 10)`. If this is the level of reduction you are looking for that's a viable option. However, there is some level of obfuscation involved so there is a trade-off consideration. What I've posted is as far as I'd personally take it. But i can post some other interesting options

Comment: Rather than `a` I might name the function something still very short (and cryptic), but also at least somewhat descriptive; maybe `pt`. But probably not. I also find the first snippet here much more readable, and copy/paste means it's not really more work to write.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
        Dim NewPoint As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Point) = Function(left As Integer, top As Integer)
                                                               Return New Point(left, top)
                                                           End Function
        Dim myPoints As List(Of Point) = New List(Of Point) From {NewPoint(50, 50), NewPoint(80, 50), NewPoint(110, 80), NewPoint(80, 110), NewPoint(50, 110), NewPoint(20, 80)}
        myGraphics.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, myPoints.ToArray)
```